# Mapping function for apex sharing

Tags: apex, sharing, apex-managed-sharing

So I'm trying to create a function that allows you to create a sharing rule through Apex with any Object. Is there a way to generalize this so I don't have repeating code? From what I understand the sharing object is the name of your SObject with '__Share'. So my method would be customShareMapping(String apiName, String shareWith, String accessLevel);

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That logic only applies to *custom* object sharing, and only if the object isn't public read/write. Standard sharing uses various specialized tables, such as AccountShare or CaseShare (to name a couple). A full solution would involve some heavy lifting, and probably wouldn't be worth it. However, let's say you wanted to approach it, your algorithm would be something like:

- Describe the object (apiName), and see if isCustom() is true or not.
- If not custom, consult a mapping table to determine which share table to use.
- If custom, append __Share to the apiName to determine which share table to use.
- Try to describe the share table resolved above.
- If not custom, and table exists, use some specialized handler to determine which fields to set.
- If custom, able table exists, use generic algorithm to create shares (they all work the same).

You may also need/want a "share reason" parameter. Standard shares can only be "manual", but custom shares might include custom sharing reasons.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. A quick question on the Standard sharing - do all Standard objects support this? If not, would the said (apiName + 'Share') object error out? Also, is this possible for Master Detail objects? For a Master Detail would you have to find the parent object and perform the Share on that?

Comment: Not all objects have a share (and some only when settings are appropriate). Master-detail objects mean you'd have to find the parent, either by iterating through all fields, describing, and figuring out which one to use. To figure out the existence of a table, use Schema.getGlobalDescribe().